# UIViewController popover presentation - unwanted top offset

Tags: ios, autolayout, uipopovercontroller

Presented ViewController very simple = UITableView with header.
What is it? And how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: You can remove a table view header by setting it's height to 0. However, this looks like a custom view, perhaps? In which case, you're gonna have to find the view in your code, before we can help you.

Comment: Solved. this is unwanted top constraint on tableview. Trait variations with changing constant to 0 has no effect for viewcontroller popover presentation.